# Why does my ajax code just gets to error result?

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp

I wrote ajax code that works by hitting a button.

```
<button onclick="clearMessage()" value='myButton'/>
```

These two are the functions to perform by the button.

```
function clearMessage(){
    var insertedMessage = document.getElementById("insertedMessage").value;
    sendMessage(insertedMessage);
    document.getElementById("insertedMessage").value="";
}   
function sendMessage(insertedMessage){
    $.ajax({            
    type:'POST',
    url:("<c:url value='/sendMessage.do' />"),
    data:'message='+insertedMessage,
    success:function(res){
        alert("Success!!!");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Fail!!');
    }
});
```

The URL for ajax is '/sendMessage.do', and a method of a Controller has the RequestMapping below.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sendMessage.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

FYI, this project is in Spring MVC, and I made sure that "sendMessage.do" is only assigned to one method.
Hope that I can find a clue to solve ......

Comment: And the error is? Stacktrace???

Comment: I just get Fail message by the alert('Fail!!').....

Comment: Try `url: '/sendMessage.do'` instead of `url:("<c:url value='/sendMessage.do' />")`

Comment: It will only call that error if there is also something wrong on the server side. Check your logs.